# Advanced GCSE Indices

Tags: fractions

At school, we've been asked to simplify the following:
$$\left(\frac{S^{9/10}}{S^{3/5}}\right)^{-4}$$
I've given it a go but haven't been taught this yet. Could someone please explain the process which one would use?

Comment: You've got the basics of LaTeX nailed down, that's for sure. Note that you can make bigger brackets (which I did in your question) with `\left(` and `\right)` instead of the usual ( and ).

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{S^a}{S^b}\right)^c=(S^{a-b})^c=S^{ac-bc}$$